# How print json response in php

Tags: php, cakephp, json

I have the json object from remote site. When I `vardump` the json response. The output looks like this..

```
object(GSResponse)#111 (7) {
  ["errorCode":"GSResponse":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["errorMessage":"GSResponse":private]=>
  NULL
  ["rawData":"GSResponse":private]=>
  string(1808) "{
  "UID": "*********",
  }
  ]
  }
```

How can I access the **rawData** parameter in the json response using php. Is there any function to convert it into php array.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** - updated to include the comments

## Answer

Lets say that $gsresponsevar is an object of type gsresponse, as defined below.

decode the json response-

```
$myjsonresponse= json_decode($gsresponsevar->getResponseText()) ;
```

**Alternatively** retrieve the var

```
echo $gsresponsevar->getString('uid');
```

### Documentation

Extract from: http://developers.gigya.com/030_Server_SDKs/PHP/Reference/Class_GSResponse

```
string  getString(string $key [, string $defaultValue])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the getString it works. I didn't even have to use the json decode. But is it the only way to get values from the object. is there a way to the get the entire rawdata as an array.

Comment: you could cast the object as an array, $array = (array)$theObject; then accessing it like $array['"errorCode":"GSResponse":private'] should work :)

Comment: Have you tried  `->getResponseText()` what's the output from that?

Answer (score 1):

**this is the generic "frameworkless" native way**

you can use [JSON_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode a JSON-string

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

$dataObject = json_decode($json);
$dataArray = json_decode($json, true);
```

The second parameter defines whether you get an object (accessible via $dataObject->key) or an associative array (accessible via $dataArray['key']).

Be aware of the common mistakes mentioned in the API "Example #3 common mistakes using json_decode()"

**This is the Gigya-API usage way**

See the answer from Jason for more details for this

```
$responseObject->getString('key');
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use json_decode($json_array);

for print your resulted array you can write `var_dump(json_decode($json_array));`

Thankx.